# Redux setting state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I am new to redux and I can not figure out how to update state using data fetched from the API.
What I want to do is to fetch data from the API and update the initial data, which is my state but I cant figure out how to do so.

```
const initialData = {
        weather:"",
        country:"",
        temp:"",
        main:""
    }

    const api = {
    key: "03cd6f70ae1d6d28cbbecedd10d3ed34",
    base: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/"
    }

    const WeatherReducer = (state=initialData,action) => {

        switch (action.type){
            case "UPDATE_WEATHER":
                const query = action.payload

                const search = () => {
                    fetch(`${api.base}weather?q=${query}&units=metric&APPID=${api.key}`)
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .then(result => {

                        temp = result.main.temp
                        
                    })
                }

                search()
                return{
                    // weather: weather,
                    // country: country,
                    // temp: temp,
                    // main: main
                    ...state
                }
            default:
                return state
        }
    }

    export default WeatherReducer
```

Comment: It is not recommended to perform any kind of `async` task in the reducer. Reducer should be a pure function. **NO SIDE-EFFECTS**. Use `redux-thunk` instead.

Comment: You can read [this](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic) page from redux official docs

Comment: Also, it would be good to directly learn modern Redux, following the "Essentials" tutorial in the official docs. You are learning a style of Redux here that we do not recommend to be used in any production application that is started now. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts (also whatever tutorial you are following right now is giving you quite wrong ideas on what to do where)